# User defined outline-minor-mode-highlight

Tags: highlighting, outline

I want to give the user the ability to change the outline highlighting setting.  After taking the user option I call the `intern` function to use the appropriate symbol required by `outline-minor-mode-highlight`.  Is this the correct way to do it ?

```
(defun taxocask-outl-focus (actm)
  "Setting for outline-minor-mode-highlight."

  (interactive
   (let ( (completion-ignore-case  t)
      (cseq '("t" "append" "override")) )
     (list (completing-read "Outline-Highlight: " cseq nil t))))

  (setq outline-minor-mode-highlight (intern actm)))
```